# read xlsm file in js

Tags: javascript, xlsm

I'm reading xlsx file in javascript using following code:

```js
this.parseExcel = function (file, id) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            var data = e.target.result;
            var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {
                type: 'binary'
            });

            var template_row_object = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_csv(workbook.Sheets['Template']);};
        reader.onerror = function (ex) {
            console.log(ex);
        };
        reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
    };
};
```

code is working fine for xlsx file but I want to use the same code for reading xlsm format.

Answer (score 0):

Using `readAsBinaryString` is discouraged (it was once removed but brought back for backward compatibility). in fact the hole `FileReader` is legacy now with the new promise based blob reading methods.

```js
this.parseExcel = async function (file, id) {
  const uint8 = new Uint8Array(await file.arrayBuffer())

  const workbook = XLSX.read(uint8, { type: 'array' })

  const template_row_object = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_csv(workbook.Sheets.Template)
}
```

It may not answer your question but I guess xlsm is different format that XLSX do not support.